# How to sit 2 iframes side by side in the center?

Tags: html, css, iframe, center

I am trying to sit 2 iframes side by side and have them both in the center of a page. The DIV that surrounds them has all text etc in central but the iframes sit either left or right based on the align tag but not in the middle.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <iframe src="iframe content" width="64" height="65" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" align="left">
    </iframe>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="iframe content" style="height:20px;" align="right">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box iframe{
    display:inline-block;
}   

.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
.box{ text-align:center;}
```

for iframe you can use float left as well. or else even display: inline-block is fine as well.

Comment: text-align:center doesn't make a difference and display:inline-block centers both iframes but moves the second onto the next line...

Comment: it should not sit in center without text-align center property.

Comment: try float:left otherwise if display:inline-block is not working.

Comment: float:left sits the two side by side but not in center - they now sit to the left. I think they were centered before as they sit with in a div that has text-align: center

Comment: yes you have use both. for div text-align:center, and for both iframes float:left.

Comment: They still sit to the left, CSS is now:

Comment: They still sit to the left, CSS is now .box{text-align:center;} .box iframe{float:left;}

Comment: then display:inline-block for iframes should be given. and from top give margin-top:30-40%.

Comment: display:inline-block centers the iframes but puts them on seperate lines. margin-top makes the div they are in huge